# How are the difficulties of called shots determined in Dwarf Fortress adventure mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

In Dwarf Fortress adventure mode called shots (aimed attacks as they're called in the game), have two modifiers.

- Difficulty (Chance to hit)

  - `Easy Strike`
  - `Tricky Strike`
  - `Difficult Strike`
- Squareness (Damage Modifier)

  - `Can only graze`
  - `Square`
  - `Very square`

How are these things determined, and can they be manipulated to give me an:

`Head     Easy Strike, Very Square`

Answer (score 2):

Weapon skill is the best way to increase this. I have a legendary +10 swordmaster, and he can make these hits like it's nothing.

Comment: I was more asking if maneuvering effected what was easy versus hard, instead of how to make it easier.

Comment: so far the combat system hasnt been fully released on how it works. From what [Dwarf Fortress Wiki](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Combat) says getting better skills as well as armors/weapons is all that can really be determined at this point.